# How to process GET requests in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, http, search

I need to add several checks when user **manually** inputs URL with params on my site.

For example, if user types *mysite.com/?random=text* I want to redirect him to custom page (let's imagine that I forbid using var *random* and I want users to be redirected in such cases).

How can I do this in WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
add_action('parse_request', 'my_custom_url_handler');
function my_custom_url_handler() {
   $redirect_url = 'https://google.com/';

   if ( isset( $_GET['random' ]) && $_GET['random'] === 'text' && $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == '/' ) {
      wp_redirect( $redirect_url , 404 );
      exit;
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much @ArtemyKaydash, I guess this is exactly what I need! I'll try this solution a bit later and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with JavaScript, it's not really related to Wordpress:

```
window.onload = function() {
    const queryString = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    const random = urlParams.get('random')
    if(random === "text") {
        window.location.href = "https://google.com/";
    }
}
```

It's also possible with php, but I think JS is the easiest way.

Comment: Man, I've dealt with a similar solution on one of the projects, and it was a freaking headache to find why some pages redirect users sometimes. Definitely not the easiest and not the best way to do this.

Comment: thank you @ChrostipSchaejn, but my task is to do this using PHP